# to ebb vs to dwindle vs to dissipate

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

What is the the difference between the verbs dwindle, dissipate and ebb in terms meaning?

to *dwindle* means:

> Diminish gradually in size, amount, or strength
>
> Though she was many miles away, he felt her aura gradually dim and
>   dwindle until it faded completely away…

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dwindle

to *dissipate* means:

> to gradually disappear by becoming less strong, or to make something
>   do this
>
> (With reference to a feeling or emotion) disappear or cause to
>   disappear
>
> The concern she’d felt for him had wholly dissipated
>
> He wanted to dissipate his anger

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dissipate

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dissipate

to *ebb* means:

> (Of an emotion or quality) gradually decrease
>
> He sighed, a bit of the anger ebbing away from his countenance

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ebb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all mean something like *reduce* but the means of reduction changes in each case.

*Dwindle:* become smaller without spreading.  A pond *dwindles* as the sun dries it up.

*Dissipate:* Become less concentrated and fade away.  A column of smoke *dissipates* as the wind blows it around.

*Ebb*: Reduce the level of something.  The tide *ebbs* as it drops from the daily high tide to the daily low tide.

> Over time, his anger *ebbed/dissipated/dwindled*.

Any of these three would work fine - they have slightly different flavors, as suggested above.